# Which is the longest own-goal in football?

Tags: football, trivia, own-goal

In an recent International Champions Cup match between Chelsea and Inter Milan, Inter's [Geoffrey Kondogbia](https://youtu.be/awQP4qtv44Q?t=598) scored 45-yard own goal.

Is this the longest own-goal ever scored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been many 40-yard+ own-goals, in my pick two own-goals that are definitely longer than Inter's Geoffrey Kondogbia is [Quevilly Rouen’s player](http://wittyfutty.com/2016/08/video-quevillys-player-scores-goal-half-pitch/) half the pitch own goal for Pau in 3rd French league and Bleacher Report article claiming **50-yard** own-goal of [Borussia Monchengladbach's Christoph Kramer](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/2279531-the-10-most-embarrassing-own-goals-ever)

Video links: [Christoph Kramer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtLvmNA5GVM), [Quevilly Rouen’s player](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4qkodf)

Other long range own-goals: [Joshua Rose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nTl_KpcdNk), [José Ángel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPQCFgEctAg)